# For loop to determine if similar variables in case/control pairs

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple for loop but I am not sure how to go about it. 
I have a set of data which is grouped (4 controls to 1 case [500 cases overall]). I was to look at each group and see if they also have similar information on another variable and have the output "true/false" if more than two in the "group" have the same value for that variable.

[this is an example of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe1Yp.png)

the output I would expect from this would be 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE

This is what I have so far

```
num_rows=nrow(data)
for(i in 1:num_rows){
  if(Pair.ID=data[i,1]{
```

and I have no idea how to finish it...Iknow it is very basic stuff but I am just not sure how to phrase it in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to evaluate properties by group, `dplyr`'s `group_by` is very useful.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Pair.ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
                   Group = c("G2", "F2", "F6", "H1", "G2", "J2", "T1", "J7", "B2", "F3", "F3", "Y6", "F3", "W2"))
```

I first use `group_by(Pair.ID)` to define the groups and then summarize the data frame with `summarize` and define the new column `Same.Info` which is `TRUE` if any information in the Group column is duplicated for this group and `FALSE` otherwise.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Pair.ID) %>% 
  summarize(Same.Info = any(duplicated(Group)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Pair.ID Same.Info
#     <dbl>     <lgl>
# 1       1      TRUE
# 2       2     FALSE
# 3       3      TRUE
```

An approach without using `dplyr` and with a for-loop.

```
n_group <- 3

for (i in 1:n_group){
    cat(i, any(duplicated(data$Group[data$Pair.ID == i])), "\n")
}

# 1 TRUE 
# 2 FALSE 
# 3 TRUE
```

Here the result for checking each group are simply printed to the console with `cat`, but ofcourse they could be stored in a vector, list, etc.